# Single page checkout for shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Kindly please suggest me the best way to single page checkout for Shopify store. As Shopify doesn't support any customization to the checkout page. Our requirement is to create a single page checkout. let me know how it is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Shopify does not support customization in the checkout page. It is only available to Shopify plus Customer. Please visit [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/layouts/checkout) for more information.

You want a single page checkout you may need to create your own checkout process which will again require your store to be a Shopify Plus store. However, there are many Apps which can help you with single page checkout. You may want to use one of them if you don't want to build the whole functionality. You may want to check the below conversation - [Link](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/We-Need-A-One-Page-Checkout/td-p/480806)

Comment: When I will get shopify plus account, then I am able to change my checkout page to single page checkout ?

Comment: Yes, you can but you need to do a lot of customizations. Better you get an App which does the same. Please check the second link i have provided.

Comment: While I have chat with Shopify support he told me currently, there is no way of editing the checkout to appear like this. Not even on a plus store. I have confirmed this with the technical team. This is so we remain compliant with PCI regulations and that the checkout remains secure

Comment: There are a few apps which help you get the feature. You should give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Shopify if you want to make your own Checkout. Shopify is a hosted platform and they no longer want to let people play with the cash register themselves.

Of the few Apps that remain that do offer checkout outside of Shopify, you can see the hassles involved for customers. Why not just roll your own? If you can do your own checkout, hook up to an open source system instead where you can do that easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough to do if you have the skills. Basically create an app that has a proxy page and change the theme's links replacing the paths to the checkout with paths to your proxied checkout.

There are a number of ways to collect payment info if you do this including using the draft_orders api to send the customer back to Shopify for final payment (not applicable for single page checkout but sometimes works well with the business reason that justifies a custom checkout in the first place)

You can also create a sales channel app that works much like the proxied app concept but has some more api capabilities.

However you really need a good business reason for doing this. Single page checkout was fashionable a few years ago but I've had as many customers go away from it as go towards it. Shopify has done quite a lot of work on their checkout and it works well (i.e. is fast and efficient) on all their supported platforms. Creating a custom checkout means your stuck maintaining it and are potentially increasing your liability if you take credit cards but have not received PCI certification.